# What's the difference between Evoland and Evoland classic?

Tags: evoland

On [Evoland's website](http://evoland.shirogames.com/), it has a link to [Evoland Classic](http://evoland.shirogames.com/classic). What's the difference between the two games?

- Is the story the same?
- Is there more gameplay?
- What changes are made to the interface when not a web game?

Answer (score 2):

Well the main difference is that they had more than 48 hours to make it since it's from a Lundum Dare competition.

The story begin almost the same has the classic but you'll go much further in the game with now a better story, you have to save the world ! You have more monsters and some bosses too.

The gameplay has been modified to be able to play with a touch display device, maybe on mobile phone later? But for now if you have a computer with touch display enable, you'll be able to play with you finger, but trust me, keyboard is better.

The interface is begin from a basic one hit kill with a sword to a full health gauge with hearts and 3 main weapons:

> Sword, Bombs and Bow

So of course that the game is much evolved than the classic version. Sincerely, this is the best indie, RPG remake game I've played in years and worth every pennies.